# array_slice() oldest entry

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array in `$comments` and I only want to allow 3 arrays inside it.

To do this, I use:

```
$comments = array_slice($comments, 0, 3);
```

Now, whenever there is a new array added, I want to remove the oldest (first) one and add the new one. How do I do this?

Currently, it keeps only the first 3 arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a negative offset:

`$comments = array_slice($comments, -3, 3);`

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

> If offset is negative, the sequence will start that far from the end
>   of the array.

Depending on what you're trying to do, [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) might also be useful.

Comment: It works. I will accept in a moment, thank you.